# want to call a function onblur inside the rule block in JQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a situation like this:

There is a text box in my form which takes a value to create an account. So whenever I give some value to the text box and move out of it by pressing TAB, it validates for existing value for the field through a REST call.

Now say if the value already exists, it throws an error. Now if I go back to the same text box and start typing, the validator sends the rest call for every stroke of the keyboard. But my intention is to send the rest call only when I move out of the box(onBlur, onFocusout).

Can someone point out how to achieve this.

```
jQuery("#form").validate({
    rules : {
        Name : {
            validNameRule : true
        }
    }
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("validNameRule", function(value, element) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
           //contains the rest call to check if the name already exists
      });
},"");
```

So this validNameRule method is called for every keyboard stroke after the validation triggers for the first time.

Comment: why not using onchange?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent sending REST calls on each key press by adding attribute `onkeyup` to false. But still `onfocusout` will perform your validation and send REST calls on clicking outside the textbox.

```
jQuery("#form").validate({
    rules : {
        Name : {
            validNameRule : true
        },   //Dont forget this comma
    onkeyup: false   //Added this line
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VGjYw/8/ This is the fiddle but I cant give in the rest call I am using. and it is throwing some errors regarding validation as well.